# Internet Explorer moves webpage elements by itself

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I have an interesting dilemma. For an IT course, I have to design a website with a weather database, which I have done. It displays nicely in Chrome and Firefox (and I assume Safari), and for the most part in Internet Explorer.

However, as you can see in these screenshots, IE seems to take it upon itself to move links and buttons when the user moves their cursor near them.

**Figure 1 - IE Layout before moving cursor to copyright link:**
[image]

**Figure 2 - IE Layout after moving cursor to copyright link:**
[image]

**Figure 3 - As compared with Chrome:**
[image]

The website address is http://penguinweather.tk. Please feel free to look around if it will help. The problem also occurs on the [confirmation page](http://penguinweather.tk/Database.php) (again only in IE).

Here is the most relevant code from the homepage:

```
<body class="body">
    <center>
        <h1>Penguin Weather</h1>
        <h2>Weather Database</h2>
        <h3>Welcome to Penguin Weather! You can enter new data here, or click on the second button to view all current weather data.</h3>
        <form action="Database.php" method="post">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Location:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" class="textbox" name="loc" autofocus>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Temperature:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="number" class="textbox" style="width:75px;" name="temp">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="password" class="textbox" name="pass">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" class="button" style="font-weight:bold;" value="Save Datum">
            <br>
            <br>
            <a href="DataOutput.php" class="button">View Weather</a>
            <a href="/pw/DataOutputV2.php" class="button">View Weather by Month</a>
            <a href="/pw/ModifyData.php" class="button">Modify Weather</a>
        </form>
    </center>
</body>
<footer>
    <center><a href="/auth.html" target="_blank">Copyright &copy; 2016 Penguintech Ltd.</a></center>
    <br>
    <center><small><a href="/dev" target="_blank">View Development Directory</a></small> | <small><a href="/404">Test</a></small></center>
</footer>
```

Thank you in advance.

(PS: Don't click on the penguin unless you like harmless annoyances!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that Internet Explorer did not like the `<center>` tags, so wrapping the page in a `div` with CSS formatting solved the problem.

**Code:**

```
<div style="text-align:center">
*page content*
</div>
```

And to keep the table centred:

```
<table style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto">
*table content*
</table>
```